# Fix "AddEventListener" error in IE11 without access to Master Pages

Tags: javascript, infopath, master-page, internet-explorer

After editing a form in InfoPath for use on a SharePoint 2010 site, my page will no longer load on IE11. On all other browsers, it is fine, but before the page can load in IE11, I receive a "Critical Error" message that states: "Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'". According to a StackOverflow post that I found (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829292/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-error-in-ie11), the solution to this problem is to either run IE11 in compatibility mode or to insert the following code in the Master Page"

```
<script language="javascript">  
/* IE11 Fix for SP2010 */ 
if (typeof(UserAgentInfo) != 'undefined' && !window.addEventListener) 
{ 
    UserAgentInfo.strBrowser=1; 
} 
</script>
```

I would rather not ask all my users to run their IE11 in compatibility mode, and I currently don't have access to the Master Page. Does anyone know if there is any workaround that I can use to solve this problem aside from the two previously mentioned solutions?

EDIT: Changed script.

Comment: Note that there should be a `</script>` at the end of this HTML snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've run into this problem and have had to fix it via the master page. If you don't have that luxury, the only other thing I can think of is to have the IT folks set up a group policy to enforce it globally.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn321457.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Adding the javascript to the master page is ideal, but if that is not an option, then an alternative is to use Content Editor Web Parts.

1. Add a text file to a library containing the JavaScript snippet. (One place to put it could be the Site Assets library.
2. On each page that has an InfoPath form, add a Content Editor Web Part. Assign the CEWP to read its source from a file, specifying the path to the text file you added in Step 1.

Comment: This or the Code Snippet web part should be the solution. Makes it super-easy to do client-side rendering modifications.

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue, but I just realized that if you activate Enterprise mode in IE you can skip this issue.
Hope that helps
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Adding the site to the IE Compatibility View Setting worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code snippet in JS file used in master page or used globally.

```
<script language="javascript">
if (typeof browseris !== 'undefined') {
    browseris.ie = false;
}
</script>
```

For more information refer blog: http://blogs2share.blogspot.in/2016/11/object-doesnt-support-property-or.html

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the page to be fully loaded

```
window.onload=function() {
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){console.log("worked", e);})
}
```

It worked for me